# Grant types in WSO2 API store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

When I register an application in WSO2 API store, I am allowed to check most of the grant types except the following grant types:
- Code and 
- Implicit

How can turn ON the code grant type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a `Callback URL` (as shown in below image) to generate tokens with `code` and `implicit` grant types. After providing a callback URL, click on `Generate Keys` button.

[image]

Comment: I had the callback url. My invocation looks like the following curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 'https://127.0.0.1:8243/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3Pgte6Wh3yismuz1nu7SMTxG1m8a&scope=PRODUCTION&redirect_uri=https://localhost.com' -v -k and it returned with the following: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Location: https://127.0.0.1:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error.do?oauthErrorCode=unsupported_grant_type&oauthErrorMsg=Requested+Grant+type+is+not+supported.

Comment: In the WSO2 API store, under the application, all grant types are checked, but the "code" grant type is unselected. Not sure, if that is causing the issue of unsupported grant type ?

Comment: looks like you have misunderstood my answer. So I attached a screenshot.

Comment: I now have updated the callback URL. However, when I try to invoke the endpoint to get the authorisation code like in the link below, I don't receive a url in the response with query param ?code= . I have attached a screen shot to my original question.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to update questions with different questions after an answer is given. The problem is when someone else reads the question and answer, they will be confused. So I suggest you to remove your new question from this, and create  a separate question.

Comment: Advise well taken!